# is it still a copy constructor when you only copy the pointer instead of the entire data?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So let's say I have a class called classname and this class has `char*` private data member.

In the class that I am taking, the professor wants us to do it like the one below, essentially creating a completely new array.

```
classname(const classname & source)
{
         c_string = new char[strlen(source.c_string)+1];

         strcpy(c_string, source.c_string);

}
```

But what if the two objects essentially share the same single array(that has already been created), like this one.

```
classname(const classname & source)
{
         c_string = source.c_string;
}
```

I understand this doesn't necessarily do any 'copying' and having different pointers (that belong to different objects) might be risky. But is it considered a copy constructor? Or is it so that in order for it to be a copy constructor the second array must also be created?

From what I've been reading I feel like the second one is the case, but I need a definite NO THAT'S NOT A COPY CONSTRUCTOR to be completely over this in my mind.
Thank you.

Comment: it is a copy constructor, because it has proper signature

Comment: Copy constructor is defined by its signature, *not* the content in the function body.

Comment: Correct syntax does not imply correct design. There are things compiler can do. The rest is the designer's job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: You are doing a [shallow copy rather than a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) but it's still a copy-constructor.

Comment: Another example of a *legal* copy constructor `classname(const classname & source) { /* This space intentionally blank */ }`. You probably won't write that, but this is what the compiler will synthesise for a class with no data members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commenters have all correctly pointed out, what you have **is** a copy constructor, regardless of the function's content.

It's a copy constructor because the standard says so ([see 12.8.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)):

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (...).

Since you have a non template constructor for `classname`, whose signature matches `const classname&`, you have a copy constructor. Maybe not a great copy constructor, maybe a broken one which doesn't even copy, but a copy constructor nonetheless.

Since I can't say it better than those who have commented, I'll simply quote them:

> Copy constructor is defined by its signature, *not* the content in the function body.- [@liliscent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578215/is-it-still-a-copy-constructor-when-you-only-copy-the-pointer-instead-of-the-ent#comment84152652_48578215)

> You are doing a [shallow copy rather than a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) but it's still a copy-constructor.-[@acraig5075](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578215/is-it-still-a-copy-constructor-when-you-only-copy-the-pointer-instead-of-the-ent#comment84152754_48578215)